# Generalization of urn problems in probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

While simple urn problems - given $x$ green and $y$ black balls, whats the probability if we take $6$ that $2$ will be black etc. are easily solvable with hypergeometric and binomial distribution. Is there a distribution that solves it a general case for example:

Given $1000$ blue, $1200$ green, $2000$ red balls we draw $20$ balls.
If at any point the number of green balls drawn cubed minus the number of red balls squared is greater than the number of blue balls to the power of $2,5$ we add to the urn:

1. The number of green balls drawn as green
2. Twice the number of red balls as red
3. Cubed the numbers of blue balls as blue.

What is the probability that at the end the red balls will be more than the green and the blue combined?

Is this solvable?

Comment: What's the question?  The rules seem rather bizarre and random (not to mention incomprehensible).

Comment: Given 1000 blue, 1200 green, 2000 red balls we draw 20 balls.
Let x be the number of drawn blue balls currently, y-green, z-red.
If at any draw this condition is satisfied: y^3-z^2>x^2.5 . We add ONCE to the urn this configuration and continue the drawing:
1. The number of green balls drawn as green 
2. Twice the number of red balls as red 
3. Cubed the numbers of blue balls as blue.

Comment: If for whatever reason these rules are actually of interest, I'd suggest sampling the process.

Comment: The rules are given as an example, my question is : Is there a general way to solve this?

Comment: Like I say, I suggest sampling.  Especially if the rules are random and subject to change.  Any analytic solution is going to depend heavily on the exact nature of the rules.